# PHP - как упростить проверку ключей в массиве?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив, в котором в котором может или не может присутствовать ключ ['newValue']

```
$array_json['value'][$i]['fields']['Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork']['newValue'];
```

либо может быть

```
$array_json['value'][$i]['fields']['Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork']
```

И таких ключей, которые могут быть или не быть достаточно много.
Можно ли как то упростить проверку что ключ ['newValue'] есть или нет сразу для нескольких элементов?
Например:

```
 $array_json['value'][$i]['fields']['Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork']['newValue'];
 $array_json['value'][$i]['fields']['Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Change']['newValue'];
 $array_json['value'][$i]['fields']['Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Time']['newValue'];
```

Просто если проверять каждый ключ по отдельности - получается громоздкая конструкция.

Comment: использовать цикл foreach?

Comment: Можно поменять архитектуру массива чтобы под элементом `'newValue'` был список `Microsoft....`. Тогда можно проверять пустой или нет. А если менять нельзя, то добавить эту копию для ускорения. Это будет оптимизация поиска ключа по значению и занимает память в два раза больше.

Comment: и чего вы дальше сделать то хотите, проверили, дальше что? В приведенных строках у вас 2 параметра меняется. вынесите проверку в функцию. Функцию оберните в цикл, или два.

Comment: Да можно конечно и в функцию. Проверять все равно также придется каждый ключ. Дальше из этих ключей ['Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork'] или ['Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork']['newValue'] в зависимости от значений выполняются дальнейшие операции.